# How to initialize stack object from pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, root-framework

When I have a pointer to an object, how do I create a non-pointer variable from it?

My situation is this: I have a TFile class that loads files. These can contain various different named objects. TFile has a `Get` method (returning `void*`) that lets me retrieve one of those objects. What I usually do is:

```
TFile file("filename", "READ");
TTree* tree = (TTree*) file.Get("treename");
```

Now what I'd like to do is to be able to declare `TTree tree` as a non-pointer instead, and have it initialized from the returned pointer. Is there any way of doing this (preferably without copying the object, and without editing the source of `TTree`)?

Comment: No it's not going to be possible without copying. And depending on your implementation of `TFile` and `TFile::Get` it might even lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the syntax of a non-pointer object, use a reference:

```
TTree& tree = *static_cast<TTree*>(file.Get("treename"));
```

(Note that I replaced the C-style cast with a `static_cast`, which is not necessary, but usually considered good style.)

Note, however, that if you had to delete the `TTree*`, declaring it as a `TTree&` will not free you from this duty.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't think about making a reference from a pointer. About cleanup: The library I'm using ([ROOT](http://root.cern.ch)) is a bit murky there. The documentation neither says who has ownership of the return value, nor how to release it. Usually it doesn't matter if you leak, since typical programs are short-lived, but it still leaves one with an uneasy feeling.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but you may need to test for NULL `void *pVoid = file.Get("treename");  if (pVoid) {TTree &tree = *static_cast<TTree *>(pVoid); ...}`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a reference to the object, provided the lifetime of the object is sufficient:

```
Tree & tree = *static_cast<TTree*>(file.Get("treename"));
```

Be sure to check the documentation of `TFile` for a guarantee that the object lives at least as long as your `tree` variable.